# How to calculate Deviation with three independent variables

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I have an equation which calculates damage in a video game Final Fantasy 14. After initial damage is calculated the game does three roles to determine extra damage. The first role is any integer between -5 to 5 for standard damage variation: 95% of damage to 105%. The second role is to determine if it is a critical hit. This will have a set percentage chance depending on gear for this example lets go with a one in four, 25% chance to do critical damage. This is a yes/no to do roughly 50% more damage. Finally the game roles to see if you direct hit which is a flat additional 25% more damage and we can go with a 10% chance for this. All three of these rolls are compounded with normal damage.

How would I go about measuring the standard deviation to show expected results given enough attempts?

The calculator I designed in excel is located at the below link and you can go to the Baka 1 tab to see expected damage, absolute low, and absolute high. I simulate 500 attacks each of which would get a roll described above.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ELscgnbpYvE2nie5o8hdURsb4ODE8-ky1SIEB8d9Z8M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This isn't very clear.  I don't understand the sentence "This will have a set percentage chance depending on gear for this example lets go with a one in four, 25% chance to do critical damage. This is a yes/no to do roughly 50% more damage. "  Also, what do you mean by "compounding" the various damages?  When there is an addition $25\%$ damage, do you add $.25$ or multiply by $1.25?$

Comment: @saulspatz: I take the sentence you quote to mean that there's a $50\%$ probability to do $25\%$ more damage. From column $Q$ of the spreadsheet, I gather that "compounded" means that all factor are multiplied, for a maximum of $1.05\cdot1.25\cdot1.5$.

Comment: But I have a question myself, @David: What do you mean by "measuring the standard deviation to show expected results given enough attempts"? You don't need the standard deviation to calculate the expected damage.

Comment: Joriki is correct

Comment: I can calculate and I guess I am calculating the expected damage. However each time I go through a run there is natural variation in the damage based on the chance of doing critical damage. So assuming infinite runs I can take the chance at face value. However I would like to know on any given iteration of the 500 hits what the expected damage maths out to.

How to put this more cleanly. Assuming an infinite number of tests there will be an instance where everything rolls high damage (All critical hits, all direct hits, all +5% damage). I want to make a graph or just say

Comment: that the expected value range of one standard deviation is XXX amount to the left, average I have but could get mean, and one deviation to the right XXX damage